# How to copy data from one table to another when foreign key is only defined in the destination table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys, schema

**Table_A** schema:

```
Id (PK, int)
Name (nvarchar(40))
UserId (**FK**, int)
Date (datetime)*
```

**Table_B** schema:

```
Id (PK, int)
Name (nvarchar(40))
UserId (int)
Date (datetime)
```

Column `UserId` is defined as Foreign Key in `Table_A`.
I need to copy data from `Table_B` to `Table_A` and I used:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_A ON

INSERT INTO Table_A ([Id], [Name], [UserId], [Date])
    SELECT [Id], [Name], [UserId], [Date] 
    FROM Table_B
```

But I get:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserId"
>   The conflict occurred in database "Table_A", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.

Table `Users` exists of course.

FYI & BTW 
This situation is due to the unfortunate fact that the [SO Demo Db](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) has no FK information.
See [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250490/there-are-no-foreign-keys-constraints-in-the-data-explorer-database)

Comment: You can't. This is how a relational database enforces relational integrity. You can drop the FK or just select the rows that don't offend the FK or populate the foreign table with the missing data.

Comment: Cascade option might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you really needed to get those records in you would join to the users table to ensure you had vaild userid's:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A ([Id], [Name], [UserId], [Date])
    SELECT EData.[Id], [Name], EData.[UserId], [Date] 
    FROM Table_B EData
INNER JOIN Users FKData on FKData.UserID = EData.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to copy data from source to target table when there are foreign key constraints created in target table.

Comment: If that were the case then you would never be able to enter data into any table that had a FK defined on it.  That would literally make your DB useless.

Comment: We cannot say DB is useless here.
We need to understand the scenario more to get the right solution. We can write stored procedures to copy records from one to another table based on some logic.